# Product is repeating on next page automatically in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

Link of my site: http://www.classiquefurniture.com.au/index.php/

I have entered some products in this category: http://www.classiquefurniture.com.au/index.php/bookcases.html but some products are repeating automatically on 2nd page as well but thing is, the product is entered only once in backend. And some product is not displaying on any page.

Now one more strange thing: When I choose option (12 products per page) then some products are not displaying on any page but likewise when I choose (all product in one page) those products are displaying.

I don't know why this is happening. Its really surprising for me. Please help me in this matter.

Comment: It looks okay right now. Can you specify which products did you found repeating in pagination ?

Comment: You can find "SOMMERSET BOOKCASE" on both first & second page an d 3 product having name "SHELBY" which is not display on any page but when you select all then "SHELBY" is displaying and "SOMMERSET BOOKCASE" will only display once means perfect.  @Chiragit007

Comment: A simple solution might be to enable the flat product catalog of Magento under

System > Config > Catalog > Frontend
After reindexing, Magento will use the flat table for the store view on product listing pages on the frontend.
It might be that solves the issue already for you.

If it doesn't solve your problem, try adding another sorting criteria, for example the entity_id.

You can do that using an event observer for the catalog_product_collection_load_before event. ($observer->getCollection()->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');).

Comment: Hi Should I write this in answer so that you can verify ? This can be helpful to future programmers.

Comment: @UditGupta Was this problem happening for you in private window also or even after clearing browser cache ? do you remember ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to enable the flat product catalog of Magento under  System > Config > Catalog > Frontend After reindexing, Magento will use the flat table for the store view on product listing pages on the frontend. It might be that solves the issue already for you.  If it doesn't solve your problem, try adding another sorting criteria, for example the entity_id.  You can do that using an event observer for the catalog_product_collection_load_before event. ($observer->getCollection()->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');).